# Multi languages translate on react app by i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I want to make my react app able to translate to different languages simply.
I found this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@ricklee_10931/react-multi-lingual-with-react-i18next-57879f986168

I have already app that I want to add the option to translate to some languages.
Do I have to add every single text to the json and translate manually every piece of text? or there is a easier way to translate my react app?

Comment: You could write a script to read your json file and generate other json files for other languages using some translation API, like Google Translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to add every piece of text in json file, but for translating, you can use [POEditor](https://poeditor.com) to translate automatically

Comment: instead of i18next? or in addition?

Comment: In addition, it translated complete JSON file